ftplib doesn't send files in celery bot
I used a code from here to download files in Selenium Grid VMs, but, when I use FTP, it shows no error and it doesn't send the files.
Code from ftp bot
def is_connected(ftp):
        try:
            ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        except (socket.timeout, OSError, AttributeError):
            return False
        return True

@shared_task()
def send_binary(file_name : str, file_path):

    ftp = FTP(
        FTP_FAT_HOST,
        FTP_FAT_USER,
        FTP_FAT_PASSWORD,
        timeout=30
    )

    ftp.set_pasv(True)

    ftp.encoding='utf-8'

    if(not is_connected(ftp)):
        ftp.login()

    upload_to_ftp(file_path, ftp)

def upload_to_ftp(local_file, ftp : FTP):
    try:
        with open(local_file, 'rb') as file:
            ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {os.path.basename(local_file)}', file)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Erro ao enviar {local_file}: {e}')

Code I use to download pdf e txt files from my sources
def __download_file(self, file_name: str, target_directory: str) -> None:
        if not os.path.exists(target_directory):
            os.makedirs(target_directory)

        contents = self.driver.execute(Command.DOWNLOAD_FILE, {"name": file_name})["value"]["contents"]

        zip_target_file = os.path.join(target_directory, f"{file_name}.zip")
        with open(zip_target_file, "wb") as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(contents))

        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_target_file, "r") as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall(target_directory)
        os.remove(zip_target_file)

Does anyone know another way to make it work ?
I tried creating a bot in celery just to ftp, before this it was inside my main code. I tried change the ftp server, I tried change the ftp passiveness and timeout. Nothing changed.
